# Is it possible to run windows application on windows azure

Tags: .net, winforms, azure, service, azure-web-app-service

I have now a dedicated server runs some of my website, and we implemented a windows application which do some file manipulations for uploaded files of one of the websites, this windows application also connects to Task Scheduler to start tasks.
I am thinking now to move to windows azure, and I am trying to know if it possible to use the same app on windows azure, and in this case I should use virtual machines or I can use web sites or cloud services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, by "Windows application," you mean some type of Win32 console app that you run, then you can run that in either a Cloud Service (web/worker role) or Virtual Machine. With the former, you'll just need to download/setup the Windows app in your startup script - you can download from blob, or even include it in your deployment package, although that increases pkg size, slowing down upload when redeploying, and tightly coupling the win app to your deployment pkg.

With Virtual Machines, you'd just need to install the Windows app one time on the virtual machine. You could then make an *image* of the virtual machine, which you can use as a baseline for virtual machine deployments.

With Web Sites, you cannot install any additional exe's - you don't get any access to the machine running your code (no RDP, etc).